# Getting values from multiple JSON objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js

I would like to add names to multiple JSON objects at the same time.

I tried this:

```
let jdata = fs.readFileSync('participants.json');
let json = JSON.parse(jdata);
jury = ["jury1", "jury2"];
for(i=1; i<3; i++){
    data = json.jury[i];
    console.log(data);
}
```

My JSON file:
{
  "jury1": [
    "name1",
    "name2",
    "name3"
  ],
  "jury2": [
    "name1",
    "name2",
    "name3"
  ]
}
This gives me an error:

```
            data = json.jurys[i];
                              ^
```

TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined

I haven't used JSON before and i'm not sure how to get all of the values from these objects. Could someone tell me what i'm doing wrong? Thanks for your time and help already!

Comment: Use square brackets like this `data = json[jury[i]];`

Comment: I know whats wrong now @gurvinder372 explained it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined

Your `json` doesn't have a `jury` attribute.

So, `json.jury` returns `undefined` and hence your error.

Make it

```
for(i=0; i<jury.length; i++)
{
    data = json[jury[i]]; //notice the change here
    console.log(data);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so so much, I edited the loop so it gets both objects, but it works now! Can't thank you enough!